# How save space in HTML table when exporting to PDF Django / Python

Tags: python, html, css, django

I have a very simple table that takes all employees working on one specific adress and returns me a list of names that looks like this:[image]

My question is how can i make the table fill the entire page so that instead of 3 pages or more i have 1 page with rows side by side to save space when printing.

The layout right now is

Page1: Name (break)
Page2: Name (break)
Page3: Name (break)

i want something like this:
Page 1: Name | Name | Name (saving as much space without breaking page.)

The code i have tried using so far is this:

```
    <style type="text/css">
        @page {
            size: letter portrait;
            size: Letter;
            margin: 1.0cm;

        }

        body {
            font-size: 10pt;
        }

        . {
            padding: 4px;
        }

        table {
            border-collapse: collapse;
        }

        table,
        th,
        td,
        tr,{
          word-wrap:break-word;
          table-layout:fixed;
          border: 1px solid black;
          margin-top: 50%;
          text-align: left;
          padding: 8px;
        }

        .wrap {
            width: 50%;

        }

        .left_col {
            float: left;
            width: 48.4%;
        }

        .right_col {
            float: right;
            width: 50%;
        }
    </style>

</head>

<body style="margin-bottom:1px;">
<div>
    <h1>Jobsite: <b>{{location}}</b></h1>
    <h4>Date: <b>{{date}}</b></h4>
</div>


<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
    </tr>

    {% for item in data %}
        <tr><td>{{forloop.counter}} - {{ item.LastFirst }}</tr></td>
    {% endfor %}

    <h5>Manager's Signature: _______________________________________</h5>
</table>


</body>

</html>
```

And this is where i handle the view:

```
@login_required()
def download_pdf(request, location_name):
    current = CurrentInfo()
    pdf_data = current.detail_employees_by_location(location_name)  # this gives me the list of people

    pf = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(pdf_data, orient='index', columns=['EmployeeNumber', 'LastFirst'])
    data = pf.drop_duplicates()
    count = data.count()
    data = data.to_dict('records')
    today = datetime.datetime.now()

    response = HttpResponse(content_type='application/pdf')
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="report.pdf"'
    html = render_to_string('user_area/template_download.html',
                            context={
                                'data': data,
                                'location': location_name,
                                'date': today
                            })

    pisa_status = pisa.CreatePDF(html, dest=response)

    if pisa_status.err:
        return HttpResponse('We had some errors <pre>' + html + '</pre>')
    return response
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Easiest solution I can up with is to put several `td` elements next to eachother.
The `forloop` has several attributes as you noticed. We can use that for decision making.
Note that I added a `colspan=3` to the th to make it span all three columns.

Could not test the Django HTML code, so it could be slightly off ;)

```html
<body style="margin-bottom:1px;">
<div>
    <h1>Jobsite: <b>{{location}}</b></h1>
    <h4>Date: <b>{{date}}</b></h4>
</div>
<table>
    <tr>
        <th colspan="3">Name</th>
    </tr> #changed the for loop to accept remainder operation.
    {% for item in data %}
        {% if forloop.first or forloop.counter0|divisibleby:"3"%}<tr>{%endif%}
            <td>{{forloop.counter}} - {{ item.LastFirst }}</td>
        {% if forloop.last or forloop.counter|divisibleby:"3"%}</tr>{%endif%}
    {% endfor %}
</table>
<h5>Manager's Signature: _______________________________________</h5>
</body>
```

Some explanation, I use two different versions of `counter`, the zero based and normal one. Reason is that I'm not 100% sure if Django template parses the + 1 correctly otherwise. In python I'd do this:

```py
In [2]: for i in range(100):
   ...:     if i==0 or i % 3 == 0:
   ...:         print('<tr>')
   ...:     print(i)
   ...:     if i==99 or (i + 1) % 3 == 0:
   ...:         print('</tr>')
```

Output of this is similar to what I have in mind:

```
<tr>
0
1
2
</tr>
<tr>
3
4
5
</tr>
```

```
{% if forloop.first or forloop.counter0 % 3 == 0 %}<tr>{%endif%}
```

If it's the first iteration, or if it's a '3rd one':  start a `<tr>`,

Similar, but for the closing tag:

```
{% if forloop.last or forloop.counter % 3 == 0 %}</tr>{%endif%}
```

If it's the last item, or it was a '3rd one', close the tr.

Comment: I do see the logic in the code and it makes sense to me, however it does not work in django and i don't seem to understand but it gives me this error : '' Could not parse the remainder: '%' from '%'  "

Comment: I have found the solution based on your code i had to make minor tweaks. I will update your asnswer. THank you very much my friend

Comment: Nice! Wasn't able to test it locally! Adjusted my answer after your suggested edit :)

Comment: Also the second for loop is uncessessary, it  will create empty cells in the table. My friend thank you again so much and specially for explaining your thought process after the answer.